# In node.js, is there any way to identify a unique call stack / tick interval?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am wondering if there is any (performant) way to identify a unique tick in the event loop?

I **don't** want to do anything like:
1) throw an exception, collect a callstack, analyze it, and hash it, or
2) subprocess any OS or external processes to collect a process / thread ID for uniquness

It should be a language construct. The API I would prefer would be

```
process.tickId
```

Comment: How do "call stack" and "tick interval" relate?

Comment: The node.js primitive process.nextTick will add a function to be called at the next "tick" in the event loop. At that point, a new call stack will be started by the event loop.

So if you take two possible points of failure in that call stack, they'll share two things: 1) parts of the call stack and 2) the unique iteration of the event loop (because JS is single-threaded)

Comment: That would require for me to register a callback on every tick, which I am guessing is not something that should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
Handle<Value> tick = process->Get(String::New("tickId"));
if (!tick->IsNumber()) {
    tick = Number::New(0);
}
process->Set(String::New("tickId"), Number::New(tick->NumberValue() + 1));
```

To each of the cases of `MakeCallback` in `node.cc` would provide the counter `tickId`. I tested this but I don't know if it leaks memory.